# How can I put a colored square inside a <button> element instead of some text?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="setThemeColor(this.name)">Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="setThemeColor(this.name)">Black</button>
```

The buttons are used to allow the user to select a theme color. Can someone tell me how I can replace the words with a square of color ?

Comment: Just create a div instead of a button and style it accordingly.

Comment: It's as easy as just creating a <div> inside the button and style it. Check this example http://jsbin.com/eCUrObA/1/

Answer (score 5):

Make the button solid and give the background colour this way:

```css
button.red {border: 1px solid #f00; background: #f00;}
button.blue {border: 1px solid #00f; background: #00f;}
```

Or, if you want the button to have some padding, use a `<span>` and not a `<div>`, as button is an **inline** element and `div` is a **block** element, you are not supposed to nest a block element inside inline element, and style the same way as above. Something like this:

```
<button class="red"><span></span></button>
```

And the CSS:

```css
button.red span {border: 1px solid #f00; background: #f00; display: block;}
```

#### Preview

[image: Buttons]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/8Waxm/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button class="set-theme blue">•</button>
<button class="set-theme red">•</button>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button.set-theme {
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: .5em;
  padding: 0 .2em;
}

button.set-theme.blue {
  color: blue;
}

button.set-theme.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Close but the OP wants a square, not a circle.

Comment: I fail at geometry :(

Answer (score 0):

find the simple reduced code CSS. just delete color names as text only in HTML code

```
button {padding: 5px; border:0; width: 10px; height:10px;}
button[name="darkBlue"] {background: #005AAE;}
button[name="black"]  {background: #000;}
```

Hope this helps, happy coding.

Comment: This is a bad practice. Use classes!